# Why is the audio delayed both in preview and render in after effects

Tags: video, after-effects, editing, audio, adobe

I have a problem with after effects, the video is alright but whenever I render or preview it the audio is delayed. The problem is not during the render it occurs during preview and its only one video that contains sound that is on my timeline, the preview is ok at first but at some points on the timeline the audio begins get mixed up. I checked the waveform of the audio of the video and it was ok, but when I preview or render it gives problem, this problem occurs in all the adobe products I have- after effects cc, cs6, 2015, and premiere pro

Comment: Have you considered deleting all your media render, preview, and cache files?

Comment: It also sounds like audio-drift too: https://youtu.be/lLQOyaYkhkA

Comment: What will happen, if you will work only with wav-files (files wothout compression, pure PCM)?

Comment: To me it seems more like an audio driver problem. The outputted media should be good, try to render it and play it on another machine, I guess that the file would not have problem. Investigate on your hardware and software better, try changing / updating the sound driver. Check if you haven't some extra effect costantly applied on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd been stuck with the exact problem before and in my case it was an issue of [VFR](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1110005).

Apparently, Adobe products do not support videos with variable frame rates. So whenever you work with such videos the A/V goes out of sync.

Try re encoding the video to a constant frame rate using FFmpeg or handbrake.

Answer (score 1):

Try making sure the video format you're using for the comp is the same as your source video file, e.g. same frame rate, same audio sample rate, and same resolution.  The suggestion about converting the file to a PCM WAV file 48kHz 16 bit is a good one too.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine had the same problem and the only thing that resolved it for him was using **lossless** for the output module render settings. Then after the render, to get the AVI file size down, he used a third party program to apply some lossy compression to it.